# Displaying iPhone UDID on Prefrences/Settings?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to display the iPhone Unique Device Identifier number in the main settings/preference screen outside of the application?

If so, how is this done, as I can't see how to pull the UDID into Root.plist.

If not, I'm able to display it in a normal iPhone Application view, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... this is possible!

1. you need to create an app that will store values to iphone settings page.
   (google about it)
2. you need to get the device guid. 
   here's a link http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/06/objective-c-get-iphone-device-guid/

---

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Stanza](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=284956128&mt=8) does this somehow — so, I guess it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by displaying it "in a settings/preference screen". Is this a screen in your application? You can get the unique identifier from `[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier` and you can use it anywhere in your application. So if this screen is in your application then of course you can display it.